# custom events to constructor javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, prototype

newbie to javascript. I have a non DOM function I would like add events to the constructor.

```
var class=function(){
/*
some code
*/

}
class.prototype.add=function(){

/*
adding item*/

}
```

now I would like to add event to the custructer

```
var klass=new class;

class.onadd(function(){
/*execute on adding item*/
});
```

I would attach it with different functions many times.

How can I add event and call the functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's broken into two parts, the `on` which collects handlers, and the event triggers, in you case is the `add`

The `on` collects the handlers according to the event assigned:

```
function yourConstructor(){
  this.events = {};
}

yourConstructor.prototype.on = function(eventName,handler){
  //create a property in `this.events` called `eventName` and put an array
  //in that array, store all handlers for that `eventName`
}
```

Then your function, in this case `add`, executes their specific handlers:

```
yourConstructor.prototype.add = function(){
  //do what add does
  //then execute all handlers in this.events.add array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own eventing system, however I don't recommend it. There are plenty of good librairies for that already. Here's a few:

- [EventEmitter](https://github.com/Wolfy87/EventEmitter)
- [js-signals](http://millermedeiros.github.io/js-signals/)
- [microevent](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/microevent.js)
- [asEvented](https://github.com/mkuklis/asEvented)

I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scarsick/CbmBw/) to show how you could use microevent.

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.sayName = function () {
    alert('My name is ' + this.name);
    this.trigger('nameSaid');  //trigger the nameSaid event
};

//Make Person instances observable by applying the MicroEvent mixin
MicroEvent.mixin(Person);

//Create a new Person instance
var o = new Person('John Doe');

//Listen to the nameSaid event
o.bind('nameSaid', function () {
    alert(this.name + ' just said it\'s name!');
});

o.sayName();
```